# Bigquery - How to zip two arrays into one?

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

If I have two arrays in BigQuery that I know are of equal size. How can i zip them into one array of structs or an array of two element arrays or similar?

The following query gives me all possible combinations of x and y which is not what I want.

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT
    ['a', 'b', 'c'] as xs,
    [1, 2, 3] as ys
)
SELECT struct(x, y) as pairs 
FROM test, unnest(xs) as x, unnest(ys) as y
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| pair.x | pair.y |
+--------+--------+
| a      | 1      |
| b      | 2      |
| c      | 3      |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `WITH OFFSET` and the bracket operator:

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT
    ['a', 'b', 'c'] as xs,
    [1, 2, 3] as ys
)
SELECT struct(x, ys[OFFSET(off)] as y) as pairs 
FROM test, unnest(xs) as x WITH OFFSET off;
```

Comment: Hi @Elliot, just wondering, is there somewhere in BigQuery docs that describes this `WITH OFFSET` operation? I was looking for it but couldn't find :).

Comment: It's part of the [Query Syntax topic](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest), but not part of Functions & Operators (which is a natural place to look). I will follow up with our tech writers to make this more discoverable; it should maybe be part of Working with Arrays as well.

Comment: oh got it! thanks for the help :)! Indeed first places I looked for was Functions and Operators and then Working with Arrays lol.

Comment: Thank you for this! Worked like a charm!